# .NET приложения на виртуалке при большой нагрузке

Tags: .net, производительность

У нас на сервере имеется несколько виртуалок с установленными на них сервисами, что написаны на .net, в определенные моменты они могут выедать до 8 гб оперативной памяти и почти весь CPU, в этот же момент они выпадают, причины выпадания не ясны - но происходит это во время пиковых нагрузок, может ли это быть связанно с тем что они находятся на виртуальных машинах?

**Обновление**

При завершении процесса не вызывается событие AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException - следовательно, скорее всего система сама завершает процесс

Comment: у Вас падают каких то конкретные виртуальные машины или вся система?

Comment: Падают сервиса и виртуалки очень сильно лагают, что к ним нереально подконнектиться через rdp

Comment: обычно жависты (а дотнет недалеко от нее ушел) говорят - доставьте планку памяти. Иногда это решение оправдано. Возможно, можно поднять ещё одну машину и перенести туда часть виртуалок.

А потом посмотеть, кто именно тормозит (возможно Вы уже знаете, какой именно сервис обычно первым вылетает - можно с него и начать) и снять дамп памяти. По нему попытаться угадать, что же там происходит. Следующим этапом будет воспроизведение в девовском окружении и оптимизации слабых мест.

Comment: Сервиса и так понятно какие вылетают, там идет непрерывное выжирание CPU и памяти, и когда нагрузка подходит к 100% процесс просто завершается - другой вопрос - почему они завершают свою работу, есть предположение что это связанно с тем что он хостится на виртуалке, может быть настройки виртуалки ?

Comment: При завершении процесса не вызывается событие AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException , следовательно скорей всего система сама завершает процесс

Comment: Ваше приложение хочет выделить ещё памяти, а ее нет. И негде взять. А приложению нужно. Что сделает в этом случае система? правильный ответ - прибъет приложение. И это правильно. А работает это на виртуалке или нет - какая разница.

Почему же не вызываются события и исключения? да нет память для их вызова.

В целом - ищите, кто жрет память и фиксите его. То, что в .NET не нужно вызывать деструктор и есть GC, ещё не значит, что не нужно следить за памятью.

Comment: Дело в том, что память остается свободная, потому что ее очень много на сервере, и система там 64bit, так что дело не в памяти

Comment: много - это сколько? С другой стороны, есть такая штука как фрагментация памяти. 

А может Ваше приложение пытается выделить несколько сотен гигов памяти.

Comment: 8 ядер, 14 гб памяти, сервисы до 8 все вместе

Answer (score 1):

x64 .net приложение не может умереть всего на 8Gb. занятой памяти (тем более при наличии 14Gb физической). Судя по описанию - тормоза, не работает даже RDP - есть два варианта:

- памяти на самом деле меньше, система начинает активно свопить -> тормоза.
- памяти на самом деле меньше, система начинает свопить, натыкается на битый диск -> еще большие тормоза.

Читайте логи на виртуалках на момент падения процесса, хотя бы станартный Event Log - если система убила процесс - там будет запись.

Добавляйте логгирование в своих сервисах - возможно у вас где-то есть выход по таймауту, который срабатывает из-за тормозов.